# Add text to json C ++

Tags: c++, json, qt

There is a JSON file, how can I add information there so that the past is left? Did something like this, does not work:

```
QFile File(pathJSONProject);
File.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text);
QJsonParseError JsonParseError;
QJsonDocument JsonDocument = QJsonDocument::fromJson(File.readAll(), &JsonParseError);

QJsonObject json = JsonDocument.object();

json.insert("Расстояние", dlgOpen->distance);
json.insert("Размер", dlgOpen->size);
json.insert("Путь", pathFolder);
QJsonDocument document(json);
File.open(QFile::WriteOnly | QFile::Text | QFile::Truncate);
File.write(document.toJson());
File.close();
```

I want to add entries to the file. Can't do it. It does not change.

First, is the file like this? How does he have to add new entries?

```
{
    "Name": "45",
    "Path": "C:/Users/Dmitry/Desktop/45.json"
}
```

How to add a new entry to the array?

[image]

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Could you show us json file before and after you write it?

Comment: I want to add entries to the file. Can't do it. It does not change.

Comment: Close the file after you read the contents, before opening it again in WriteOnly mode.

Comment: thanks, and how can I add to the record (array)?

Comment: QJsonDocument doc;
    QJsonArray arr;
    arr.append(.......);
    doc.setArray(arr);
    doc.toJson();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always handle the return value of `QFile::open()` to check whether it was successful or not.

---

There can be multiple ways to insert an array in JSON. Here's an example:

```
#include <QDebug>
#include <QJsonDocument>
#include <QJsonObject>
#include <QJsonArray>

int main()
{
    const auto data = R"({ "Name": "45", "Path": "C:\file.json" })";

    auto doc = QJsonDocument::fromJson( data );
    qDebug() << "BEFORE:\n\n"
             << qPrintable( doc.toJson( QJsonDocument::Indented ) );

    // Create an array and add objects
    const auto obj1 = QJsonObject{ { "name", "abc" }, { "default", 11 } };
    const auto obj2 = QJsonObject{ { "name", "xyz" }, { "default", 22 } };

    auto obj = doc.object();
    obj.insert( "array", QJsonArray{ obj1, obj2 } );

    doc.setObject( obj );
    qDebug() << "\nAFTER:\n"
             << qPrintable( doc.toJson( QJsonDocument::Indented ) );

    // Add more objects to array

    const auto obj3 = QJsonObject
    {
        { "name", "def" },
        { "default", 33 },
        { "new1", "1" },
        { "new2", "2" }     // Add any number of objects...
    };

    const auto obj4 = QJsonObject{ { "name", "jkl" }, { "default", 44 } };

    // Get existing array to append more elements
    auto arr = doc.object()[ "array" ].toArray();
    arr.append( obj3 );
    arr.append( obj4 );

    // Set old array to newly updated one
    obj[ "array" ] = arr;

    doc.setObject( obj );
    qDebug() << "\nAFTER THAT:\n"
             << qPrintable( doc.toJson( QJsonDocument::Indented ) );

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**:

```
BEFORE:

 {
    "Name": "45",
    "Path": "C:\file.json"
}


AFTER:
 {
    "Name": "45",
    "Path": "C:\file.json",
    "array": [
        {
            "default": 11,
            "name": "abc"
        },
        {
            "default": 22,
            "name": "xyz"
        }
    ]
}


AFTER THAT:
 {
    "Name": "45",
    "Path": "C:\file.json",
    "array": [
        {
            "default": 11,
            "name": "abc"
        },
        {
            "default": 22,
            "name": "xyz"
        },
        {
            "default": 33,
            "name": "def",
            "new1": "1",
            "new2": "2"
        },
        {
            "default": 44,
            "name": "jkl"
        }
    ]
}
```

---

Also, take a look at [QJsonArray::fromStringList()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsonarray.html#fromStringList) and [QJsonArray::fromVariantList()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsonarray.html#fromVariantList).

Comment: Thank. And if I then want to open this file and add the same elements to the array to the end.

Comment: And tell me how then to work with this array? Parsing certain data from it is convenient?

Comment: @Optimus: Depends on the availability of data. If you already have a complete JSON string you can use `fromString` family of functions. If you have dynamic data, you can create new and/or manipulate existing objects to populate a new JSON.

Comment: The data will be constantly updated. but I control it. everyone will have a unique indicator

Comment: @Optimus: Right. Yes, it is quite convenient once you get the hang of Qt JSON APIs. These are pretty straightforward. If you have something specific beyond the scope of this question, you can look at Qt documentation. And, if you get stuck somewhere, you can always post on SO.

Comment: Запись массива. Было вот так: http://prntscr.com/n1kizw
Сделать вот так: http://prntscr.com/n1kjc4

Comment: @Optimus: Check the updated example now. A ctor of `QJsonObject` takes an `initializer_list` of `<QPair<QString, QJsonValue>`. You can add any number of objects in it. Do look at it and the rest of the documentation. See doc: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsonobject.html#QJsonObject-1

Answer (score 1):

Check the return value of

```
File.open(QFile::WriteOnly | QFile::Text | QFile::Truncate);
```

It's most likely going to be `false` since you already have the file open for ReadOnly access and haven't closed it.

Answer (score 1):

To modify the data, given your example, you need to check if the contained data in the QJsonDocument is an array or a simple object. In your case, I suppose you want to append data to an array. Try something like this:

```
// Read the data
const QString filename = "example.json";
QJsonDocument doc = read(filename);

// Check that it's an array and append new data
if (doc.isArray()) {
    auto array = doc.array();
    array.append(QJsonObject{
        {"Name", "mohabouje"}, {"Path", "whatever"}
    });

    array.append(QJsonObject{
        {"Name", "mojito"}, {"Path", "whatever"}
    });
    doc.setArray(array);
}
// Write the new data
write(filename, doc);
```

A helper functions to read/write JSON documents may avoid the mistake of open/closing a file:

```
QJsonDocument read(const QString& filename) {
    QFile file(filename);
    file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text);
    const QString val = file.readAll();
    file.close();
    return QJsonDocument::fromJson(val.toUtf8());
}

void write(const QString& filename, const QJsonDocument& document) {
    QFile file(filename);
    file.open(QFile::WriteOnly | QFile::Text | QFile::Truncate);
    file.write(document.toJson());
    file.close();
}
```